# MySQL 403 forbidden error

Tags: mysql, database

I'm attempting to delete certain data from a table and this is what happens...

```
Error in processing the request.
```

I have no idea about what may be the cause.

- I've reuploaded the whole phpmyadmin *.zip* to my site
- I've created a clone database and added the same user to it
- I've added all privileges to the user that manages the database
- I've created a new user with all privileges to manage the database

None worked... The strange thing is that when I access the database from *Cpanel* I can do everything normally, this issue only happens when I access from my site.

Image with error:

[image: Image with error]

Comment: have you `grant` the privilege to do that to your user?

Comment: Can you do basics command such as select from your website? If you can its definitely an issue with privilege.

Comment: grant command cannot be used, the only way I have to grant privileges is adding them from Cpanel.

@Bdloul forgive my ignorance but how can I check if I can use the select command?

Comment: Are you sure the credentials used in the wp-config.php are the same than in cpanel?

Comment: A 403 error will leave an entry in the error log somewhere, can you see whether you can access it and get the exact message?

Comment: it's a different acocunt from the one in Cpanel. The account I use from site is external (I created it so that I can access the db without logging into the control panel each time).

I can't see any error.log file nor can find wp-config.php